# returning an array that contains an array and hash in ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

HI

is it possible to return an array that contains an array and hash from a method in ruby?

i.e

```
def something
array_new = [another_thing, another_thing_2]
hash_map = get_hash()

return [array_new, hash_map]

end
```

and to retrieve the array:

```
some_array, some_hash = something()
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, that's perfectly possible and works exactly as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You will only ever be able to return one thing. What you are returning there is an array containing an array and a hash.

Comment: yes i know, i phrased the question wrong, sorry. so would i be able to return the array containing an array and hash map?

Comment: Yes you would. Type irb on the command line for an awesome little scratchpad to try stuff out. Just keep a browser open to the API as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby methods can be treated as if they return multiple values so you can collect the items in an array or return them as separate objects.

```
def something
  array_new = Array.new
  hash_new = Hash.new
  return array_new, hash_new
end

a, b = something
a.class # Array
b.class # Hash

c = something
c.class # Array
```